# file-loader webpack 2 load directory

Tags: javascript, webpack

I've added in this config:

```
{
    test: /assets\/(\.png|\.jpg)$/,
    use: ['file-loader?name=[name].[ext]&publicPath=assets/&outputPath=assets/']
}
```

I have a bunch of images in a `assets` directory and I want it to output both for the `web-dev-server` and `dist` the same folder full of images.

I assumed that my test would pick up every `png` or `jpg` in that folder and set both public and output paths to `assets`.

However the webpack output says this isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you're using doesn't actually match your files. The only matches are:

```
assets/.png
assets/.jpg
```

You need to add a `.*` to match anything between `assets/` and the extensions. The correct regular expression is:

```
/assets\/.*(\.png|\.jpg)$/
```

If you don't want to match the `assets/.png` you can use `.+` instead, but that shouldn't really be a problem.

You can try it in [RegExr](http://regexr.com/3fmft).

---

Just to make sure there is no additional confusion: The rules in the webpack config won't include anything, they simply get applied to the imports that pass the test (match the regular expression in this case). You still need to import them in your code, which will give you the path to the output file, so your reference will be correct.